# Can I record video with CameraX (Android Jetpack)?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-camerax

Google has released the new CameraX library as part of Jetpack. It looks great for taking pictures, but my use case also require making video's. I tried googling for that, but couldn't find anything.

So, is it possible to record videos with the CameraX Jetpack library?

Answer (score 26):

Yes, we can record video using `CameraX`. I have tried to implement myself with help of Github demo for [CameraX](https://github.com/android/camera). Please refer below code may it helps you.

**Config for Video in CameraX:**

```
val videoCaptureConfig = VideoCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
    setLensFacing(lensFacing)
    setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
    setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)

}.build()

videoCapture = VideoCapture(videoCaptureConfig)

CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture, videoCapture)
```

**To Start video recording:**

```
videoCapture?.startRecording(videoFile, object : VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedListener {
        override fun onVideoSaved(file: File?) {
            Log.i(javaClass.simpleName, "Video File : $file")
        }

        override fun onError(useCaseError: VideoCapture.UseCaseError?, message: String?, cause: Throwable?) {
            Log.i(javaClass.simpleName, "Video Error: $message")
        }

    })
```

**To Stop video recording:**

```
videoCapture?.stopRecording()
```

Same above I have mentioned in Github issue comment: https://github.com/android/camera/issues/2#issuecomment-490773932

> **Notes:** There may be different in code to implementation of video recording using `CameraX`. Because this above code was developed by me without any other reference rather than Github Demo.
>
> **Please check important comment of `Oscar Wahltinez` on this answer as of 14 May 2019**

Comment: Please note that video recording use case is currently marked as hidden in the API and is in a very preliminary state and subject to change. Refer to [the javadocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/package-summary.html) for the publicly available classes.

Comment: Do not forget to add `RECORD_AUDIO` permission

Comment: Hmmm... it seems you cannot use that from Java, or maybe is the version. VideoCapture class is marked as @RestrictTo(Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP), which prevents its instantiation.

Comment: Please share the XML as well. It's difficult to understand what is the component on which video preview is being shown

Comment: @rohegde7 You can check the official CameraX sample with entire demo with XML.

Answer (score 9):

This is my solution

```
//Versions in Gradle
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta06"
def camera_extensions = "1.0.0-alpha13"

private lateinit var videoCapture: VideoCapture
private lateinit var viewFinder: PreviewView
private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
private var lensFacing: Int = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT


private val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
private var isRecording = false
private var camera: Camera? = null
private lateinit var cameraProviderFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>


//onCreate
viewFinder = preview_video_view
    runWithPermissions(*permissions) {
        startCamera(view.context)
        initClicks()
    }

 @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi", "UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
private fun startCamera(context: Context) {
    outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory(context)
    cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)

    val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(lensFacing).build()

    // Create a configuration object for the video use case
    val videoCaptureConfig = VideoCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
        setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
        setCameraSelector(cameraSelector)
    }


    //CameraX.initialize(context, this.cameraXConfig) 

    videoCapture = VideoCapture(videoCaptureConfig.useCaseConfig)

    val preview: Preview = Preview.Builder().apply {
        setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9)
        setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
    }.build()
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider())

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            cameraSelector,
            preview,
            videoCapture
        )
        
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
}

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private fun startRecording() {
    val file = createFile(
        outputDirectory,
        FILENAME,
        VIDEO_EXTENSION
    )

    videoCapture.startRecording(
        file,
        executor,
        object : VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback {
            override fun onVideoSaved(file: File) {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    showMessage(file.name + " is saved")
                }
            }

            override fun onError(videoCaptureError: Int, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    showMessage(videoCaptureError.toString() + " " + message)
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private fun stopRecording() {
    videoCapture.stopRecording()
}

 override fun getCameraXConfig(): CameraXConfig {
    return Camera2Config.defaultConfig()
}

companion object {
    private const val FILENAME = "yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"
    private const val VIDEO_EXTENSION = ".mp4"

    private val permissions = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
    )

    fun getOutputDirectory(context: Context): File {
        val appContext = context.applicationContext
        val mediaDir = appContext.externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, appContext.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
        }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists()) mediaDir else appContext.filesDir
    }

    fun createFile(baseFolder: File, format: String, extension: String) =
        File(baseFolder, SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US)
            .format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + extension)
}
```

Comment: hi , can you please help me ,where i can add video duration in your code?

Answer (score 9):

Updating on Patel Pinkal's answer.
Having beta released, we can't use VideoCaptureConfig.Builder() anymore, instead you go with something like this:

```
 videoCapture = VideoCapture.Builder().apply {
     // init config here
 }.build()
```

Answer (score 6):

**As of April 2021**

```
val videoCapture = VideoCapture.Builder().build()
val outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()


fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
}


@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private fun startRecording() {
        val videoFile = File(
            outputDirectory,
            SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS", Locale.US
            ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".mp4")
        val outputOptions = VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(videoFile).build()

        videoCapture?.startRecording(outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object: VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback {
            override fun onError(videoCaptureError: Int, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Video capture failed: $message")
            }

            override fun onVideoSaved(outputFileResults: VideoCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(videoFile)
                val msg = "Video capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d(TAG, msg)
            }
        })
    }

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private fun stopRecording() {
        videoCapture?.stopRecording()
    }
```

**Please note that this API is still restricted and is still subject to change.**

Comment: Is there a way to feed the video captured as the video is recording as of yet?

Answer (score 1):

CameraX VideoCapture use case is implemented in camera-video, released since [1.1.0-alpha30](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera?hl=th). Refer to the following:

- [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/video-capture)
- [the reference doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/video/VideoCapture)
- [sample](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXVideo)
- [youtube video](https://youtu.be/n_oIEyiYLLk)(current CameraX status)

for details.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Sergei's answer, videoCapture.startRecording() recieves VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions instead of file for camerax_version = '1.0.0-rc01', so it should be used as:

```
videoCapture.startRecording(
        VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).build(),
        executor,
        object : VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback {
            override fun onVideoSaved(outputFileResults: VideoCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onError(videoCaptureError: Int, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }
```