# Take a Video with CameraX - setLensFacing() is unresolved

Tags: android, video-capture, android-camerax

I tried to take a video with CameraX. For that I have read the SO posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56054647/can-i-record-video-with-camerax-android-jetpack) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482850/does-camerax-support-to-record-video-with-kotlin) . 
But when I copy paste the code and adjust it a little bit, there is an unresolved reference with the `setLensFacing()` method:

```
videoCapture = VideoCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
                setTargetRotation(binding.viewFinder.display.rotation)
                setLensFacing(lensFacing)
            }.build()
```

I adjust the code little bit since you do not need to pass a config object to a `VideoCapture` anymore. You can build it directly.
At this point, Android Studio is telling me that `setLensFacing(lensFacing)` is unresolved.
I am a little bit confused because on this [page](https://androidx.de/androidx/camera/core/VideoCaptureConfig.Builder.html#setLensFacing(androidx.camera.core.CameraX.LensFacing)) , there is a nice documentation and `VideoCaptureConfig.Builder()` contains `setLensFacing()`

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Camera selection is no longer done through the use cases. The code you wrote was possible until -I think- version 1.0.0-alpha08.

The way to select the lens now is by using a `CameraSelector` when binding a use case (or multiple use cases) to a lifecycle. That way all the use cases use the same lensFacing.

So you can write:

```
val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(lensFacing).build()
// Or alternatively if you want a specific lens, like the back facing lens
val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

val videoCapture = VideoCaptureConfig.Builder().build()
processCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, videoCapture)
```

Note that currently, the VideoCapture use case is hidden in the camerax API, and is still in an early state of development.

Answer (score -1):

In CameraX 1.0.0-beta11, the video capture configuration has moved from VideoCaptureConfig to VideoCapture and the lens is set in the CameraSelector Builder:

```
val videoCapture = VideoCapture.Builder().apply {
            setVideoFrameRate(30)
            setAudioBitRate(128999)
            setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
            setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9)
        }.build()

val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                    .build()
```