# How to set up CameraX for video recording android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax, google-developer-tools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxrca.png)
I have set up everything according to the documentation on Camerax but this Previewconfig is not working. I am unable to access Builder() and again that setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener is not working.
Please suggest me where I am making mistake.

Full code is available here: https://pastebin.com/iU4SZ1G2

```
private fun startCamera() {
    // Create configuration object for the viewfinder use case
    val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().build()
 // Build the viewfinder use case
    val preview = Preview(previewConfig)

    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener {
        viewFinder.surfaceTexture = it.surfaceTexture
    }

// Bind use cases to lifecycle
    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview)
}
```

Comment: You seem to be attempting to use old camerax APIs, the use case builders and the preview surface listener API has changed. You can follow [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started) to update to the newer APIs.

Comment: @HusaynHakeem is there any documentation about video recording using camera X ? I have tried to search but it seems not available

Comment: @sarah That's because the video useCase is still under development. FWIW, you can check out its [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:camera/camera-core/src/main/java/androidx/camera/core/VideoCapture.java?q=VideoCapture&ss=androidx) and how it's used in [CameraView](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:camera/camera-view/src/main/java/androidx/camera/view/CameraView.java?q=CameraView&ss=androidx).

Answer (score 2):

Google Developers have created an official Code Lab where they have shown the implementation of clicking images and recording videos using CameraX

This is the link: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#0


These are some other links you can refer to:

1. [Does CameraX support to record video with Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482850/does-camerax-support-to-record-video-with-kotlin)
2. [Can I record video with CameraX (Android Jetpack)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56054647/can-i-record-video-with-camerax-android-jetpack)
3. [Does CameraX support to record video with Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482850/does-camerax-support-to-record-video-with-kotlin)
4. https://github.com/android/camera-samples

I have also programmed the Google CodeLab myself (just the video part)
This is my GitHub repo for the same: https://github.com/aatmanvaidya/CameraX-Video-App

I am attaching the code also below.

**bulid.gradle(app)**

- Under *dependencies*

```
    def camerax_version = "1.2.0-alpha02"
    // The following line is optional, as the core library is included indirectly by camera-camera2
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX Lifecycle library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX VideoCapture library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to additionally add CameraX ML Kit Vision Integration
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX Extensions library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}"
```

- Under *android*

```
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
```

In **AndroidManifest.xml** add permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<Button
        android:id="@+id/video_capture_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="@string/start_capture"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/viewFinder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">
</androidx.camera.view.PreviewView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var videoCapture: VideoCapture<Recorder>? = null
    private var recording: Recording? = null
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
            )
        }
        viewBinding.videoCaptureButton.setOnClickListener { captureVideo() }

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private fun captureVideo() {
        val videoCapture = this.videoCapture ?: return
        viewBinding.videoCaptureButton.isEnabled = false

        val curRecording = recording
        if (curRecording != null) {
            curRecording.stop()
            recording = null
            return
        }
        // create and start a new recording session
        val name = SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US)
            .format(System.currentTimeMillis())
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/CameraX-Video")
            }
        }

        val mediaStoreOutputOptions = MediaStoreOutputOptions
            .Builder(contentResolver, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            .setContentValues(contentValues)
            .build()

        recording = videoCapture.output
            .prepareRecording(this, mediaStoreOutputOptions)
            .apply {
                if (PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
                    ) ==
                    PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    withAudioEnabled()
                }
            }
            .start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)) { recordEvent ->
                //lambda event listener
                when (recordEvent) {
                    is VideoRecordEvent.Start -> {
                        viewBinding.videoCaptureButton.apply {
                            text = getString(R.string.stop_capture)
                            isEnabled = true
                        }
                    }
                    is VideoRecordEvent.Finalize -> {
                        if (!recordEvent.hasError()) {
                            val msg =
                                "Video capture succeeded: " + "${recordEvent.outputResults.outputUri}"
                            Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            Log.d(TAG, msg)
                        } else {
                            recording?.close()
                            recording = null
                            Log.e(TAG, "Video capture ends with error: " + "${recordEvent.error}")
                        }
                        viewBinding.videoCaptureButton.apply {
                            text = getString(R.string.start_capture)
                            isEnabled = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }
            val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
                .setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(Quality.HIGHEST))
                .build()
            videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, videoCapture)

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults:
        IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXApp"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS =
            mutableListOf(
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            ).apply {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                }
            }.toTypedArray()
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the same code, I'm not able to start my video even I'm not getting event to Consumer<VideoRecordEvent> listener. Any idea?

Comment: @AsthaGarg can you tell me what exactly is the error?

Comment: You can ignore it now :) my issue was that I was not passing videoCapture use case to bindToLifecycle.